# Trying to join two tables together in the backend using SQL query, but not seeing the data from one of the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I want to get all the data from **table partner_orders** which I am. But in addition to that, I want to get the columns `displayName` and `email` from **table ds_user**.
ds_user id is the same as partner_orders dsUserId. So in the output in every array I want the email and displayName of that user with the same id to be added to the array.

However, with the way I have written the code below, I am getting all columns in partner_orders but I am not getting displayName and email added to it. What's the right way to do it

This is what I have written in JavaScript

```
  async getAllParenFinanceOrders() {
    const programOrders = await pool.query(
      `SELECT po.*, du."displayName", du."email"
      FROM partner_orders AS po 
      LEFT JOIN ds_user AS du ON du.id = po."dsUserId" `

    );
```

Comment: Please provide test data (in each table), the actual results you are getting  and the desired results for that data. All as formatted text - **no images**.  Even better provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13) and the desired results.  NOTE: You should only select 1 database.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you neeed to use backticks instead og double quotes see more about that [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

```
async getAllParenFinanceOrders() {
const programOrders = await pool.query(
  'SELECT po.*, du.`displayName`, du.`email`
  FROM partner_orders AS po 
  LEFT JOIN ds_user AS du ON du.id = po.`dsUserId`'

);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :/

Comment: i edited the code copy it again and try it please